# What does two version requirements on single line mean in a package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

I was looking through my `package-lock.json` and I came across this requirement:

```
"requires": {
    "bootstrap": ">=4.5.3 <5.0.0",
}
```

What does it mean to have two version expressions in one line like this?
I'm writing something to compare package versions and I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: https://semver.npmjs.com/, it's more commonly expressed as `^4.5.3`.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a package requirement, `"bootstrap": ">=4.5.3 <5.0.0"` means that the package requires a version of bootstrap that is greater than or equal to `4.5.3` and less than `5.0.0`. In this context it would function the same as `^4.5.3` but you could use this functionality to specify a larger range if needed. Eg: `"bootstrap": ">=4.5.3 <5.3.7"` which would make the package compatible with any version of bootstrap from `4.5.3` up to (but not including) `5.3.7`.

Comment: _"to `4.9.9`"_ is wrong - version numbers aren't just decimals, you can have e.g. 4.10.0 that would still be compatible with the requirement.